# Delegate Action Lambda with class Person

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have the following problem: I want to make a Lambda, which should print the result of the class Person. The print should look something like this: `ResetName, after (Name ==null) = True` But I get an error on p. And what is printed out now is: `NAAM PERSOON VOOR = ALFREDNAAM PERSOON NA =`

```
        Person per = new Person();
        per.Name = "ALFRED";
        output.AppendFormat("NAAM PERSOON VOOR = " + per.Name);

        Action<Person> resetName = (Person p) => { p.Name = null; };
        resetName(per);
        output.AppendFormat("NAAM PERSOON NA = " + per.Name);

        Person p1 = new Person();
        Person p2 = new Person();

        p1.Name = "KAREL";
        p2.Name = "FREEK";

        Methods.ResetName(p1);
        resetName(p2);

        if (p1.Name != p2.Name) { passed = false; Console.WriteLine("ERROR IN resetperson"); }

        return output.ToString();
```

Comment: He can't find p in this line: Action<Person> resetName = (Person p) => { p.Name = null; }; Error: 'The name 'p' does not exist in this currect context.'

Comment: Nothing wrong with that specific line as far as I can see.

Comment: If I limit it to:  Action<Person> resetName = (Person p) => { p.Name = null; };
            output.AppendFormat("resetName, daarna ({0}) = {1}\n", p, resetName(p)); I will get the error as well and function will print nothing!

Comment: You cannot use `p` in the `AppendFormat` call, as it only exists in the lambda.

Comment: How do I solve it? So that I can use p in AppendFormat?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Do you want to print the name in the `resetName` lambda? What are you trying to do? You also can't use the lambda in `AppendFormat` like that - it doesn't have a return value.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you would provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and a more clear problem statement. In particular:

- Show us the implementation of `Methods.ResetName()`, since your `resetName` delegate is apparently supposed to have the same effect is that method.
- Explain in precise terms both what the actual effect of the code should be *and* the *actual* output you want (the text you provided as sample output — `ResetName, after (Name ==null) = True` — does not look much like real output to me, but instead looks more like a description of the code's *effect*)

That said, it seems possible to m that what you really want is something like this:

```
Action<Person> resetName = (Person p) =>
{
    p.Name = null;
    output.AppendFormat("NAAM PERSOON NA = " + p.Name);
};
resetName(per);
```